# Codepen - Basic Javascript animation not working

Tags: javascript

Context - I am just trying to learn Javascript Animation and I am using CodePen. I am trying to move a div block for a certain distance. I verified my code with W3Schools code and nothing seems out of place.

Issue - The animation is not working. When I try the same code in W3Schools, try-it-yourself box, it works.

codepen link - http://codepen.io/tusharsaurabh/pen/xEoXex?editors=1111

```
var elem = document.getElementById("block");
pos = 0;

var animation = setInterval(doMove, 5);

function doMove() {
  pos++;
  console.log(pos);
  elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
  elem.style.top = pos + 'px';

  if (pos >= 200) {
    clearInterval(animation);
  }
}
```

Browser - Safari

Please let me know, how to make animation work in CodePen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes used to animate the element are `left` and `top`, which affects the element's position only when its `position` attribute is non-static (e.g. `relative`, `absolute`).

By setting the element to one of these two positions, your Codepen will start working: you can check it [here](http://codepen.io/siavasfiroozbakht/pen/NRZwZV).

More detailed information is also available [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Or just use `transform: translate(x, y);`. This can be done by using `elem.style.transform = 'translate(' + pos + 'px,' + pos + 'px)';`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, initially I used CSS3 animations but I felt I will have a lot more control over animation by using Javascript(I may be completely wrong here) and hence I wanted to do it in Javascript

Comment: @TusharSaurabh You do have more control using Javascript. But depending on what you want, you use the option that fits. Changing the `position` may cause layout issues, while `transform: translate(x, y);` is incompatible with older browsers. It all depends